# Relationship evidence for NZ resident visa - Skilled Migrant

Tags: visa, indian-citizens, new-zealand

I received an ITA letter for *resident visa* under *skilled migrant category* for me and my wife and daughter.

I am suppose to submit the application(with ITA letter attached) to London office in next 2 months.

As part of the documents supported for *relationship evidence*, doc check list says,

> You need to supply evidence of a genuine and stable partnership of at least 12 months with your partner. You could show evidence of this by supplying the following.
>
> • Marriage or civil union certificate.
>
> • Proof of shared residence (a joint mortgage, or tenancy agreements, or rent book).
>
> • Financial dependence or interdependence (proof of shared income, or bank accounts, or accounts that show money transfers to or from your account to your partner’s account). • Birth certificates of your children.
>
> • Any evidence of public or family recognition of your relationship.
>
> • Correspondence (including post-marked envelopes) to you and your partner at the same address.
>
> • Photographs of you and your partner together.
>
> • Evidence of the duration of your relationship

I currently have

```
1) marriage certificate
2) postal envelope on my wife's name and address dated 20-feb-2015.
3) postal envelope on my name and address dated 15-feb-2015.
4) passports provide the same address.
5) Birth certificate of my daughter.
6) family photograph
```

Please let me know, if these evidences are sufficient to submit.

Comment: Safe in what way to submit them? That you'll get them back? Or that they're enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have substantial evidence of a stable partnership. I would suppose that, as long as your daughter is at least a few months old (and you are named on the birth certificate as the father), and you and your wife were married at least a year ago, this would suffice to establish evidence of a "stable partnership of at least 12 months".

When I went through this same process many years ago, I found that contacting New Zealand Immigration by telephone was extremely helpful for resolving answers to questions of this type. They can tell you whether the evidence you intend to supply is likely to be sufficient for your application. (Unlike some other countries, you actually *can* contact them by telephone, and they want to help you submit a successful application.)

Answer (score -2):

Options for Partner/Spouse of NZ citizen or resident
Living and/or working in New Zealand

If your ultimate goal is to live together permanently in NZ, the overseas partner will need to obtain a resident visa. There is a specific residence category available to such applicants, called Partnership policy. There are a set of requirements that the couple must meet before residence can be granted.

The overseas partner may also apply for a Partnership work visa, if:

the couple has not lived together for 12 months yet (as is required for residence) but can show sufficient evidence of living together in a stable and genuine relationship; or
the residence is already in process, but the applicant wants to travel to NZ before residence application is finalised.
If you are waiting for the residence decision in NZ, please note that the overseas partner must be on a valid visa at all times, which in some cases means that you may need to apply for a further work visa, if your current one is about to expire.

The process of renewing a temporary class visa (such as work visa) is the same as when you applied for it the first time - your officer will need to see all of the evidence again, to make sure you still meet the policy requirements.

Comment: I am not sure that this answer is helpful.

Comment: I agree, since this applies to the overseas partner of an *NZ citizen or resident*. The OP is applying for new residency as a family unit.